# Cannot find Dependcies (from http://download.java.net/maven/2)

Tags: java, maven

I run mvn clean package -U

And i get this error message below?

```
 Could not resolve dependencies for project DD2480-Group-15:gs-maven:jar:0.1.0: Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:3.6 in java.net2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2)
```

And i have this dependcies in my pom.xml file?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is jackson deprecreated or?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked this out.

I removed that dependency from local repo and used maven to refresh the dependencies. It came without any problem. It is not the dependency the problem but the remote repo that you try to get it from.

The repository at http://download.java.net/maven/2 is deprecated, and has been replaced with https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/

**To replace your remote repository**

A) If you use your downloaded version of maven then

you must find where your maven folder in your laptop exists. Then under `conf/settings.xml` you can configure your `settings.xml`

Then under mirror tag you can configure your remote repository

[How to configure mirrors in maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

B) If you use a bundled version of INTELIJ for Maven then check this image of how you can configure your remote repositories
[image]

Comment: How do i change the URL?

Comment: I have found the settings.xml but where do i change to https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/ in the file?

Comment: Just search for <mirrors> tag and then create a mirror like described here but with the url that you want https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html . Changing only the url from the previous example would be enough

Comment: Should i change   <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>  Boug?

Comment: yes and also don't forget to let as the example the  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>

Comment: Is it only in mirror?

Comment: yes and if that does not work try with <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>

Comment: <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>

Comment: Boug i tried with this below but it didn't work <mirror> <id>mirrorId</id> <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf> <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name> <url>maven.java.net/content/groups/public/</url> </mirror>?

Comment: are you sure that the maven that you use points to that folder where you are? Are you using some IDE?

Comment: I am using VScode?

Comment: type mvn -version and check the folder if it points to the same root maven directory where you found your settings.xml. It can be that Vscode uses an embedded maven version

Comment: mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: have you changed the settings.xml somewhere inside /usr/share/maven ? If not you must go and find the settings.xml inside there

Comment: Maybe that i haven't updated the dependcies is after that i changed the settings.xml should i use some command to update the dependcies in maven?

Comment: find your .m2 folder where maven stores local dependencies. Delete everything from that folder. Next time you trigger mvn clean install it will fetch those dependencies from remote repositories again

Comment: Is .m2 folder in the conf folder?

Comment: There is another easier way to re-index dependencies. Go to the folder of the project where you can not build it. I mean the directory from where initially you run mvn clean... and you had problems with that dependency and instead run mvn dependency:purge-local-repository. Then try again building the project